# Android app getting authorization code from Oauth 2.0 client using Games.getGamesServerAuthCode

Tags: android, oauth

I'm trying to get an OAuth code with my android game to send to a server to retrieve user data securely. I'm really new to this kind of thing, but after looking around it seems the best(maybe easiest) way for me to do this is by following the steps provided http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html here.

Upon attempting to do this I've run into two problems. The first thing is that getGamesServerAuthCode is listed as deprecated. I'm wondering why this is because the article at the link above is only a couple months old. Is it not to be used?

Secondly, if I go ahead and follow the steps and use it anyway it returns STATUS_APP_MISCONFIGURED. Do I need an extra permission in my manifest file? Or do I need to list the OAuth client ID in the manifest file? Everything else from the Games API works fine, leaderboards, achievements, etc.

Just as a final note I do have two seperate OAuth client IDs, one for release and one for debug. I've tried calling getGamesServerAuthCode using both with same results. Thanks for any and all help that can be provided.

Comment: Regarding "STATUS_APP_MISCONFIGURED." I usually have this problem when running an APK that has not come from the play store.  I'm not sure if there is an easier way, but try pushing it to the play store then running that version.  
Regarding the deprecation, I am unsure, also trying to figure out

Answer (score -1):

You need Web Application Client ID, not Android type. You can create it at https://console.developers.google.com